# Were haldi ceremony and mehendi rasam a part of vedic weddings?

Tags: scripture, vedas

Is there any reference in Hindu scriptures about

1. Haldi ceremony
2. Mehendi rasam

in hindu marraige ceremony? My personal understanding is that while haldi ceremony is on Indin origin, mehendi rasam is of Arabic origin. So I wanted to know what the scriptures have to say about these.

Comment: In addition, what are the Vedic rituals involved for marriage in contrast to the modern party weddings?

Comment: Smriti compendiums like Nirnayasindhu & Smrititattva do mention the ceremony called Gātraharidrā.